# How to have access to an online MS Form responses with code?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-forms

As there is no available feature in MS Graph API to have access to MS Form responses ([LINK](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/32045494-graph-api-to-microsoft-forms)), what's the code solution to have access to shared online MS Form responses?
I know the following available approaches:

- Manually download the responses by clicking on `Responses -> Open in Excel` and then upload it to the target location (It's a completely manual process and could not be automated by a code script which is not desired at all in my case)
- Share with a group first which gives me the option to have online access to the response file by clicking on `Responses -> Open in Excel`. This time it automatically creates an excel file in the group's OneDrive instead of downloading the file. Now I could read the excel file via MS Graph API. (This solution works but I need to share the Form with a group first and then manually click `Responses -> Open in Excel` to create the excel file)

Any thought that assists to have a complete code solution is appreciated

Comment: I would stick with the above approaches. In addition, you can consider using Microsoft Flow or Power automate to perform the above to automate the above approach. AFAIK i failed to see any Graph API exposed on this so far. Being said that i would suggest you can consider filing Microsoft Uservoice - so that they can consider implementing it

Comment: Thanks Dev, yes I already upvote an open requirement for implementing MS Forms access via Graph API.

Comment: Wonderful @Amir!!

Comment: I will move this to answer. So accept it as answer and upvote it. So it can be useful to others as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick with the above approaches which you said above. In addition, you can consider using Microsoft Flow or Power automate to perform the above to automate the above approach. AFAIK i failed to see any Graph API exposed on this so far. Being said that i would suggest you can consider filing Microsoft Uservoice - so that they can consider implementing it. You upvoted the the uservoice as well.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this for what I needed recently. The documentation seems to be deliberately vague, so this may not work in the future. I used unofficial and official info from various sources on *stackoverflow* and MS documentation. There is an (undocumented) API to pull the responses but it requires an access token. In python you can use Microsoft's `azure-identity` package to get the token, then use it to request the form responses. Here's the outline:

1. the `scope` of authorization for an access token for MS Forms is: `https://forms.office.com/.default`
2. the endpoint for fetching the responses is: `https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantid}/users/{userid}/light/forms('{formid}')/responses`
   where `{tenantid}` is the Azure Tenant ID, `{userid}` is the Azure user's Object ID, and `{formid}` is the id of the form (i.e. the `id` query parameter at the end of the form's URL). This URL requires an access token that entitles the requester to get the data.
3. use one of the *Credential* object types in `azure.identity` package and call its `get_token(scope)` method with the `scope` specified above to receive the token. Depending on which type you choose, you may need to login to Azure using `az login`, or a browser login, or use the current logged-in user's credentials.
4. Use the returned token as the `Bearer` token to authorize access to response endpoint (item 2 above)

Like this:

```py
import os
import requests

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential, AzureCliCredential

# Use one of these credential objects to get an access token
cred = AzureCliCredential() # i.e. `az login`
# cred = InteractiveBrowserCredential()
# cred = DefaultAzureCredential()

# Request an access token with the following scope
scope = "https://forms.office.com/.default"

tok = cred.get_token(scope)
# print(tok)
# print(type(tok))

formid = os.getenv("FORMS_FORM_ID")
tenantid = os.getenv("FORMS_TENANT_ID")
userid = os.getenv("FORMS_ADMIN_ID")

url = f"https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantid}/users/{userid}/light/forms('{formid}')/responses?$expand=comments&$top=7&$skip=0"

# print(url)

# Provide the access token in the request header
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {tok.token}"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```