Encountering 403 Error While Trying to Access Microsoft Forms URLs, despite successfully obtaining the authentication token
I'm currently working on a project where I need to access various URLs related to Microsoft Forms from my Python backend. However, I'm facing a 403 error when attempting to do so. Here's a breakdown of what I'm trying to achieve and the steps I've taken so far:
URLs to access:
Retrieve all Forms for a Microsoft 365 Group:
https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms
Obtain details for a group form:
https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms('{formId}')
Fetch questions from a group form:
https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms('{formId}')/questions
Retrieve responses to a group form:
https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms('{formId}')/responses
Objective: Access URLs for Microsoft Forms data from backend.
Approach:
First, I log in to the MS Forms website.
Then, I append the necessary parameters (tenantId and groupId) to the URLs I want to access, and I am getting browser responses in JSON format.
Now using backend requests, I attempt to access these URLs by passing the required authentication token.
Issue: Despite successfully obtaining the authentication token using the provided code snippet, when I tried to access the Microsoft Forms URLs with the generated token, I received a 403 error.
Here's the code snippet I'm using to obtain the token:

token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token" 

data = { 

    "grant_type": "client_credentials", 

    "client_id": client_id, 

    "client_secret": client_secret, 

    "scope": "https://forms.office.com/.default" 

} 

response = requests.post(token_url, data=data) 

response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for non-200 status codes 


And here's the code snippet I'm using to access the Microsoft Forms URLs with the obtained token:

headers = { 

    'Authorization': f'Bearer {response.json()["access_token"]}', 

    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 

} 

base_url = "https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms" 

list_response = requests.get(url=base_url, headers=headers) 


I'm uncertain why I'm receiving a 403 error despite having a valid token. I followed the instructions mentioned in this post, but was unsuccessful.
Any insights or assistance on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

AFAIK, service principal authentication is not supported to call MS Forms API. You need to use delegated flows like interactive flow to generate bearer token. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65698985/how-to-have-access-to-an-online-ms-form-responses-with-code

Initially, I too got same error when I used token generated with client credentials flow to call MS Forms API like this:
import requests

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appID"
client_secret = "secret"

token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

data = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "scope": "https://forms.office.com/.default"
}

response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {response.json()["access_token"]}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

base_url = "https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/tenantId/groups/groupId/forms"

list_response = requests.get(url=base_url, headers=headers)
print(list_response)

Response:

To resolve the error, you need to switch to delegated flows for generating bearer token that requires user to login at least once.
In my case, I ran below CLI command to connect with Azure account initially in terminal like this:
az login --tenant tenantID


Now, I ran below sample Python code that uses azure-identity module by generating token with AzureCliCredential() method and got forms details in response successfully:
import requests

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential, AzureCliCredential

# Use one of these credential objects to get an access token
cred = AzureCliCredential() # i.e. `az login`
# cred = InteractiveBrowserCredential()
# cred = DefaultAzureCredential()

# Request an access token with the following scope
scope = "https://forms.office.com/.default"

token = cred.get_token(scope)

tenantId = "tenantId"
groupId = "groupId"

url = f"https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms"

# Provide the access token in the request header
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token.token}"}

list_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(list_response.json())

Response:

Reference:
How to have access to an online MS Form responses with code? - Stack Overflow by 9nut

How can I include this authentication flow in my Python Django project?

Could you post a new question by including your python django project files set up and sample code with more details? Please share new question link here

Hey here is the link of the new post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78417727/integrating-microsoft-forms-authentication-in-python-django-troubleshooting-ter
