Integrating Microsoft Forms Authentication in Python Django: Troubleshooting Terminal Error
To integrate the Microsoft Forms authentication flow into my Python Django project for accessing various forms URLs and storing form details and responses, I'm employing the provided MS Forms authentication code within my project's backend. Additionally, I've configured my project to run within a Docker container.
The MS Forms authentication code snippet, enclosed below, outlines the process:

import json 

import os 

import django.core.management.base 

import requests 

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential, AzureCliCredential 

  

# Custom Django command definition 

class Command(django.core.management.base.BaseCommand): 

    def handle(self, *args, **options): 

        # Select one of the credential objects to obtain an access token 

        # cred = AzureCliCredential()  # e.g., via `az login` 

        cred = InteractiveBrowserCredential() 

        # cred = DefaultAzureCredential() 

  

        # Request an access token with the specified scope 

        scope = "https://forms.office.com/.default" 

        token = cred.get_token(scope) 

        print("===============================") 

        print(f"{token.expires_on = }") 

        print("===============================") 

  

        tenantId = "tenant id" 

        groupId = "group id" 

        formId = "form id" 

  

        # Provide the access token in the request header 

        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token.token}"} 

  

        # Retrieve all Forms for a Microsoft 365 Group 

        url = f"https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms" 

        list_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 

        print(f"All Forms: {list_response.json()}") 

  

        # Retrieve details for a specific group form 

        url = f"https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms('{formId}')" 

        list_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 

        print(f"Form Detail: {list_response.json()}") 

  

        # Retrieve questions from a group form 

        url = f"https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms('{formId}')/questions" 

        list_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 

        print(f"Form questions: {list_response.json()}") 

  

        # Retrieve responses to a group form 

        url = f"https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/{tenantId}/groups/{groupId}/forms('{formId}')/responses" 

        list_response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 

        print(f"Form responses: {list_response.json()}") 

 


However, during execution, I encountered the following error in my terminal:

[2024-05-01 07:15:41,963] {_universal.py:475} INFO - Request URL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com:443/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'/nRequest method: 'GET'/nRequest headers:/n    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.14.0 Python/3.8.7 (Linux-6.5.0-1020-oem-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5)'/nNo body was attached to the request 

[2024-05-01 07:15:42,211] {_universal.py:503} INFO - Response status: 200/nResponse headers:/n    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400, private'/n    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'/n    'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'/n    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'/n    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'REDACTED'/n    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'REDACTED'/n    'P3P': 'REDACTED'/n    'x-ms-request-id': 'e1684310-96f3-41e4-a6eb-65211103ff00'/n    'x-ms-ests-server': 'REDACTED'/n    'x-ms-srs': 'REDACTED'/n    'X-XSS-Protection': 'REDACTED'/n    'Set-Cookie': 'REDACTED'/n    'Date': 'Wed, 01 May 2024 11:15:41 GMT'/n    'Content-Length': '1589' 

[2024-05-01 07:15:42,219] {authcode.py:254} INFO - Open a browser on this device to visit: https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A42687&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fforms.office.com%2F.default+offline_access+openid+profile&state=ZWiINUHPhfSVnRKA&code_challenge=yMrfoYd9HzvR90L03To-Dq0We8DZX5PJTjZB0mwARsw&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=b2541aafcf591b21e143423d36feea131abae1cab38f82e7e107112886f2b68c&client_info=1&prompt=select_account 

[2024-05-01 07:15:42,221] {authcode.py:264} WARNING - Found no browser in current environment. If this program is being run inside a container which has access to host network (i.e. started by `docker run --net=host -it ...`), you can use browser on host to visit the following link. Otherwise, this auth attempt would either timeout (current timeout setting is None) or be aborted by CTRL+C. Auth URI: https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A42687&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fforms.office.com%2F.default+offline_access+openid+profile&state=ZWiINUHPhfSVnRKA&code_challenge=yMrfoYd9HzvR90L03To-Dq0We8DZX5PJTjZB0mwARsw&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=b2541aafcf591b21e143423d36feea131abae1cab38f82e7e107112886f2b68c&client_info=1&prompt=select_account 

 


Your insights or assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
